# Karma test won't run

Tags: karma-runner

Please help.  I am new to testing with karma. When I run "karma start karma.local.conf.js" the Chrome browser window comes up but the test doesn't run. I think my app.js and my test.js are ok and I suspect that the issue is incorrect versions of the packages I'm loading in my package.json. I know I also need to include mocha and chai:

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
   "browserify": "10.2.3",
   "gulp": "3.8.11",
   "gulp-browserify": "0.5.1",
   "karma": "0.12.16",
   "karma-chai": "0.1.0",
   "karma-chrome-launcher": "0.1.4",
   "karma-mocha": "0.1.4",
   "http-status": "0.1.8",
   "underscore": "1.5.2"
 }
}
```

Here is my karma.local.conf.js file:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    files: [
      'http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.js',
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular.js',
      // For ngMockE2E
      'https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.0/angular-mocks.js',
      './app.js',
      './test.js'
    ],
frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai'],
browsers: ['Chrome'],
proxies : {
  '/': 'http://localhost:3000'
}
});
};
```

I can also post the app.js and the test.js if need be, but I think they are ok. I think the issue is in the package.json and getting the right versions of the npm packages I need.

Here is my app.js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ng']);

app.directive('userMenu', function() {
  return {
    controller: 'MyHttpController',
    template: '<div class="user" ng-show="user">' +
          '  Current User: {{user.profile.username}}' +
          '</div>' +
          '<div ng-show="!user">' +
          '  <a href="/auth/facebook">' +
          '    Log In' +
          '  </a>' +
          '</div>'
  }
});

app.controller('MyHttpController', function($scope, $http) {
  $http.get('/api/v1/me').success(function(data) {
    $scope.user = data.user;
  });
});
```

Here is my test.js:

```
describe('Nav Bar', function() {
  var injector;
  var element;
  var scope;
  var compiler;
  var httpBackend;

  beforeEach(function() {
    injector = angular.injector(['myApp', 'ngMockE2E']);
    intercepts = {};

    injector.invoke(function($rootScope, $compile, $httpBackend) {
      scope = $rootScope.$new();
      compiler = $compile;
      httpBackend = $httpBackend;
    });
  });

  it('shows logged in users name', function(done) {
    httpBackend.expectGET('/api/v1/me').respond({
      user: { profile: { username: 'John' } }
    });

    element = compiler('<user-menu></user-menu>')(scope);
    scope.$apply();

    httpBackend.flush();
    assert.notEqual(element.find('.user').css('display'), 'none');
    assert.equal(element.find('.user').text().trim(), 'Current User: John');
    done();
  });
});
```

Thanks in advance,

William

Answer (score 0):

```
Here is what I did to get my tests to run:

1. Run "npm install <package name> without a version number for each package in my package.json file
2. Run "karma init" to create a new config file. By default this command creates karma.conf.js
3. Modify karma.conf.js with the information from karma.local.conf.js
4. Run "karma start".  By default this command looks for a file named karma.conf.js (I had already run "npm install -g karma-cli" so I was able to run "karma start" without specifying a path
5. Next I will run "npm ls" to see what package versions were installed and create a new version of package.json for future projects.
```

Another solution might be to run "npm install" and then run "ncu -u" to update all the packages to the latest versions. That might work but I haven't tested it.